# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de usuario que inició una aplicación en c#?

Tags: c#

Con el Administrador de tareas puede verse información del cual quiero obtener el nombre de usuario (usuario sesión de Windows) que inició una aplicación:

[image: Administrador de tareas - Proceso 'notepad']

Tengo este código y no obtiene el nombre de usuario:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process[] procesos = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
 foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in procesos)
 {               
     listBox1.Items.Add(p.StartInfo.UserName);
 }
```

En el listBox1 no agrega ninguna información, dándole seguimiento: *p.StartInfo.UserName* está en una cadena vacía.

El resultado debería de ser:

- usj
- Administrador

en el listBox1.

**Quiero obtener el nombre de usuario el cual inició una aplicación**, en Visual Studio con C#

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Raul, quite las referencias a winforms y a vs, ya que tu problema radica en el codigo mas alla de esas cosas, y no tiene importancia donde lo vas a usar despues (va a ser mas facil encontrarlo para futuros usuarios, y para quienes puedan responder)

Answer (score 1):

Vas a requerir hacer uso de `System.Management.dll` como referencia en el proyecto, ahora crea el siguiente metodo:

```
public string PropietarioProceso(int processId)
        {
            string Wmiquery = "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " + processId;
            ManagementObjectSearcher Buscador = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Wmiquery);
            ManagementObjectCollection ListaProcesos = Buscador.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject obj in ListaProcesos)
            {
                string[] argList = { string.Empty, string.Empty };
                int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(obj.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));
                if (returnVal == 0)
                {
                    return argList[1] + "\\" + argList[0]; //Formato Nombre de Dominio\Usuario
                }
            }
            return "Sin Propietario";
        }
```

Y en tu ciclo para llenar la listbox:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] procesos = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Firefox");
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in procesos)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(PropietarioProceso(p.Id));
            }
```

Sustitulle "firefox" por el nombre de tu proceso.

> En este codigo hacemos uso de los objetos WMI para consultar la
>   informacion de procesos

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, estuvo perfecto.